# type mismatch when create a kotlin infix notation to nest a function to another

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, infix-notation, first-class-functions, extension-function

I am trying to create a infix notation as a extension function of `(Int) -> Int` function which is used to nest a function to another.
For example:

```
class Entry {
    companion object {
        private fun f(x: Int) = x * 2
        private fun g(x: Int) = x + 2

        private infix fun ((Int) -> Int).nest(inner: (Int) -> Int) = { x: Int -> this(inner(x)) }

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val func = ::f nest ::g
            println(func(10))
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, it created a infix notation `nest` as a extension function to `(Int) -> Int` function. It requires another `(Int) -> Int` function and nest them together.
`val func = ::f nest ::g` is equals to `val fun func(x:Int) = f(g(x))`
`func(10)` is equals to `(10 + 2) * 2`.

But I encountered a problem when I tried to extend this extension notate function to `Number` interface (for supporting all kinds of numbers).
For example:

```
class Entry {
    companion object {
        private fun f(x: Int) = x * 2
        private fun g(x: Int) = x + 2

        private infix fun ((Number) -> Number).nest(inner: (Number) -> Number) = { x: Number -> this(inner(x)) }
        // only the infix fun declaration changed ^

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val func = ::f nest ::g
            println(func(10))
        }
    }
}
```

The kotlin compiler throws an error.

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
private final infix fun ((Number) -> Number).nest(inner: (Number) -> Number): (Number) -> Number defined in ...(path of class Entry)
```

I am wondering why `Int` extends from `Number`, but `(Int) -> Int` doesn't match to `(Number) -> Number`.
If I want to extend this notation function to all functions that ask for a number and returns a number (for example, `(Long) -> Long` `(Float) -> Double` etc.), what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a `(Int) -> Int` is *not* a kind of `(Number) -> Number`. Namely, you can give any `Number` to a `(Number) -> Number`, but you can only pass `Int`s to a `(Int) -> Int`.

By your logic, I would be able to `nest` a `(Int) -> Int` with a `(Double) -> Double`, since `(Double) -> Double` is also a `(Number) -> Number` (by your logic), but that certainly doesn't make sense, does it? You can't pass a `Double` to a `(Int) -> Int`.

Your `nest` function could be written more generally with generics:

```
infix fun <T, U, V> ((U) -> V).nest(inner: (T) -> U) = { x: T -> this(inner(x)) }
```

It is possible to nest any `(U) -> V` with `(T) -> U`, producing a `(T) -> V`.